# Let $p$ be prime. Consider the sequence: $1, 2^2, 3^3, 4^4, 5^5, 6^6 \cdots \pmod p$. Prove the sequence is periodic with smallest period $p(p-1).$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be prime. Consider the sequence: $1, 2^2, 3^3, 4^4, 5^5, 6^6 \cdots \pmod p$. Prove the sequence is periodic with smallest period $p(p-1).$

This means that $p(p-1)$ is the least among all positive integers $l$ with the property that whenever $n ≡ m (mod ~l),$ we have $n^n ≡ m^m (mod ~p)$

Prove that:

(a). $n \equiv m \pmod {p (p-1)}$ implies that $n^n ≡ m^m \pmod p$

$(b).$ If $l ≥ 2$ has the property that whenever $n ≡ m \pmod l,$ we have $n^n\equiv m^m \pmod p,$ then $p(p-1) \leq l.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Using MathJax to format your question can be very helpful for those who read your question.

Comment: Same question posted by a different user a few hours earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642947/application-of-fermats-little-theorem-in-modular-arithmetic ––– curious, how does this happen?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 3):

Start with (congruences are modulo $p$)
$$
(n+p)^{n+p}\equiv n^{n+p}\equiv n^n n^p\equiv n^nn\equiv n^{n+1}
$$
that you can generalize to
$$
(n+kp)^{n+kp}\equiv n^{n+kp}\equiv n^n(n^p)^k\equiv n^{n+k}
$$
With $k=p-1$,
$$
(n+p(p-1))^{n+p(p-1)}\equiv n^{n+p-1}\equiv n^{n-1}n^p\equiv n^n
$$
so indeed $p(p-1)$ is a period.

Suppose $n^n\equiv (n+t)^{n+t}$ for every $n$. In particular, for $n=p$, we get $(p+t)^{p+t}\equiv 0$, so $p\mid t$. Write $t=ps$ and $s=(p-1)q+r$, with $0\le r<p-1$.

For $p\nmid n$, we have $n^{p-1}\equiv1$, whence
$$
(n+t)^{n+t}\equiv n^{n}n^{pq(p-1)}n^{pr}\equiv n^nn^r
$$
so that we need $n^r\equiv 1$.

Can you finish?

> The multiplicative group the nonzero elements in the prime field with $p$ elements is cyclic. So $n^r\equiv1\pmod{p}$ for every $n$ not divisible by $p$ and $0\le r<p-1$ implies $r=0$.