# if $L \geq 2$ has the property that whenever $n\equiv m\mod L$, we have $n^n \equiv m^m\mod p$, then $p(p - 1) \leq L.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods, prime-numbers

**Question**: Let $p$ be a prime. Consider the sequence

$1^1, 2^2, 3^3, 4^4, 5^5,\cdots $

modulo $p$. Prove that the resulting sequence is periodic with the smallest period $p(p-1)$.

This means that $p(p - 1)$ is the least among all positive integers $L$ with the property that
whenever$ n ≡ m\mod L$, we have $n^n ≡ m^m \mod p$. So, you have to prove that

(i) $n ≡ m \mod p(p - 1)$ implies that $n^n ≡ m^m \mod p$ and,

(ii) if $L \geq 2$ has the property that whenever $n ≡ m \mod L$, we have $n^n ≡ m^m \mod p$, then
$p(p - 1) \leq L$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Awfully similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643146/let-p-be-prime-consider-the-sequence-1-22-33-44-55-66-cdots-pmo?r=SearchResults